# Create Global Multidimensional Array dynamically in Java

Tags: java, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an Ordering System that comprises of a number of steps before the data is finally submitted and stored in the database. I have already completed and implemented the web version of the same Ordering System. Below is the Multidimensional Array in PHP that I created dynamically based on the below values.

In the first step of Order, a Plan is to be selected. Based on that plan, the total number of days will be decided.

Plan 1 - Days Served 26

Plan 1 - Meals Served Per Day 2

Plan 1 - Refreshments Served Per Day 2

Plan 2 - Days Served 5

Plan 2 - Meals Served Per Day 3

Plan 2 - Refreshments Served Per Day 0

and so on...

In the second step, starting date of the Order is to be selected. Weekends are to be excluded and only Weekdays will be counted as days served.

The PHP Multidimensional Array generated dynamically is below

```
Array
(
    [Day 1] => Array
        (
            [meal_id_1] => Unique ID //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_code_1] => Meal Name //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_type_1] => Meal //prefilled based on the selected package
            [meal_id_2] => Not Available //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_code_2] => 2 //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_type_2] => Meal //prefilled based on the selected package
        )

    [Day 2] => Array
        (
            [meal_id_1] => Unique ID //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_code_1] => Meal Name //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_type_1] => Meal //prefilled based on the selected package
            [meal_id_2] => Not Available //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_code_2] => 2 //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_type_2] => Meal //prefilled based on the selected package
        )
```

In the above code, day number is added dynamically and numeric value in `meal_id_1, meal_code_1 and meal_type_1` is also added dynamically.

To connect the App and Web Application logically, I want to post the selection from the App in similar Array.

Since I have Meals and Refreshments to be selected based on the plan, therefore I will be loading Meals for Day 1 and then based on the Plan selected Refreshments for Day 1. There will be 1 Activity for Meals, which be loaded with updated Day number and same for the Refreshments.

Using the below code, I am able to get the Unique ID of the Meals selected in an ArrayList.

```
int count = 0;
int size = list.size();

List<String> selected_meals = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        if (list.get(i).isSelected()){
            count++;

            String selected_meal_string = list.get(i).getMeal_id();

            selected_meals.add(selected_meal_string);
        }
    }
```

How can I transfer this selection to a Global Multidimensional Array so that in the final step I can post it to be saved in the database?

Comment: Why don't you store each meal in a class and then store instances of the class inside an ArrayList or List? It doesn't make sense to create a multi-dimensional array to store this information, this is what classes are designed to do.

Comment: @JamesMacca I am a newbie and don't really know how to do it. A reference code would be of great help.

Comment: Sure no worries, I will post an answer.

Comment: Really appreciate @JamesMacca. Waiting...

Comment: Sorry for the wait, had to do something first. I have answered now, hope it helps, you may need to do some more research into how Java works first though.

Comment: It is OK. Spending time for the community is in itself a great job. Will try the solution and let you know. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my comment I think you are really looking to use a class here, please see the example below to get you started. You may require some research into how OOP (Object Oriented Programming) works though.

```
public class Meal {

//I dont know what type of data each attribute is supposed to be so I chose ints. Feel free to change.
private int mealId;
private int mealCode;
private int mealType;

public Meal(int mealId, int mealCode, int mealType){
    this.mealId = mealId;
    this.mealCode = mealCode;
    this.mealType = mealType;
}

public int getMealId() {
    return mealId;
}

public int getMealCode() {
    return mealCode;
}

public int getMealType() {
    return mealType;
}
}
```

Now the Day class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Day {
private ArrayList<Meal> meals = new ArrayList<>();

public Day(Meal...meals){
    //This uses magic params to allow you to pass in as many meals as you want.
    for(Meal meal : meals){
        this.meals.add(meal);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Meal> getMeals() {
    return meals;
}
}
```

Now wherever your main method is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Control {
public static void main(String [] args){
    ArrayList<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();

    //Create your meals.
    Meal meal1 = new Meal(1, 1, 1);
    Meal meal2 = new Meal(2, 3, 4);

    //Add the meals to a day.
    Day day1 = new Day(meal1, meal2);

    //Add the day to the list of days.
    days.add(day1);

    //Getting the meal code for the first meal on the first day. This looks complex, but you would likely break it down before getting values.
    System.out.println(days.get(0).getMeals().get(0).getMealCode());
}
}
```

Comment: Well explained.